# ImportError: cannot import name '_message' from 'google.protobuf.pyext' (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\pyext\__init__.py)

Tags: python, windows-10, protocol-buffers, importerror

I am trying this command(That I don't know what it does! I only following a tutorial):

```
tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/tensorflow/rnn_words
```

And get this result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\tensorboard.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 45, in <module>
    from tensorboard import default
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\default.py", line 34, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: cannot import name '_message' from 'google.protobuf.pyext' (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\pyext\__init__.py)
```

What does the above command do? Why do I get this error message?

```
C:\Windows\system32>python --version
Python 3.7.1

C:\Windows\system32>pip install protobuf
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from protobuf) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from protobuf) (40.6.3)
```

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1566 You can take it a look.

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade `protobuf` using the following command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall protobuf==4.32.2
```

Answer (score 1):

for me I downgraded protobuf
`pip install protobuf==3.19.6`

Answer (score 0):

According to the resolution of [tensorboard issue #1556](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1566), you should also be able to fix your problem by upgrading to tensorboard==1.13.0 (or later).

IMO, this is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Updating protobuf or using `import proto` didnt work for me. What worked was setting this env variable

```
import os
os.environ["PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION"] = "upb"
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are in mac, please try it
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall protobuf

Answer (score -1):

Works with `pip install protobuf==3.14.0` with Python 3.9

You can test with the following:

```
# python
Python 3.9.13 (main, Aug  2 2022, 11:20:39)
>>> from google.protobuf.pyext.cpp_message import GeneratedProtocolMessageType
```